# Set height of images as of other image

Tags: html, css, height

There are many questions about setting relative height to image, but non could help me. Here what I have is:

```
<div>
  <div>
    <img src='/uploads/2017/Linux_Stable.png' style='height: auto; max-width: 90%;' />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src='/uploads/2017/Open_Source.png'/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, what I want is to set the height of the image `Open_Source.png` exactly equals to `Linux_Stable.png` what ever it looks. Is it possible? How could I make it work as expected. There are other contents on each of those `div` too.

Comment: You mean something like `<img src='/uploads/2017/Linux_Stable.png' style='height: auto; max-width: 90%;' /><img src='/uploads/2017/Open_Source.png' onload="this.height=this.previousSibling.height"/>`

Comment: can you be more precise ? it's clear for me that you can specify a fixed height for your images ... but tell us the purpose and how you will be using this

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using Javascript. Just give each image an id, and then get the height of the first one using *DOM*.clientHeight for example:

```js
var image1 = document.getElementById("img1");
var image2 = document.getElementById("img2");
image2.style.height = image1.clientHeight;
```

```html
<img id="img1" src='/uploads/2017/Linux_Stable.png' style='height: auto; max-width: 90%;' />
<img id="img2" src='/uploads/2017/Open_Source.png' />
```

Comment: You can also use offsetHeight instead of clientHeight if you want to include scrollbar and borders in the height

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps if we use a container, the images can have same height as the tallest image - I am not sure how to code that.

Here are two versions

First set's height is decided by CSS as Temani Afif posted, 
Second set is decided by the first image using JavaScript

```css
.img1 {
max-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<img class="img1" src='https://lorempixel.com/200/100/' style='height: auto; max-width: 90%;' id="image1" />
<img class="img1"  src='https://lorempixel.com/200/200/' id="image2"/>
<hr/>
<img src='https://lorempixel.com/200/200/' style='height: auto; max-width: 90%;' id="image1" /><img 
     src='https://lorempixel.com/200/300/' id="image2" onload="this.height=this.previousSibling.height"
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want you could either use **CSS** to define a class and to set a fixed size for all elements of that class, just like that ..

```
/* index.css */
.myImg {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width:  200px;
    height: 200px;
}

<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='index.css'>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img class='myImg' src='‪A.png'>
        <img class='myImg' src='‪B.png'>
    </body>
</html>
```

.. or you could use **JavaScript** to get the images by their class or whatever you like and then modify the width/height attribute of the relevant image, like that:

```
<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img class='myImg' src='‪A.png' style='width:100px; height:100px'>
        <img class='myImg' src='B.png'>
        <script type='text/javascript' href='index.js'></script>
    </body>
</html>

// index.js
var images = document.getElementsByClassName('myImg');

images[1].style.height = images[0].style.height;
images[1].style.width = images[0].style.width;
```

Both methods assure that the images are the same size.